# In admin manage users page, how can I stop users with certain privileges from editing users with other privileges?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta

I've got two custom roles in my application: `super_administrator` and `liaison`.  In the context of the manage users page, super admins can do anything, but `liaisons` are read only.  Super admins can see all users registered in the application, but liaisons can only see users in the same college as them (handled through a meta key).

When a liaison is logged in and goes to the users page, I want them to be able to see all users at their college (this is already working), but not edit them.

I did some trickery with the `user_row_actions` filter to remove the edit (and delete) button, and I removed the bulk actions container whenever they're logged in as a liaison.

However, they can still click the name of a user and go to the page there and edit.  Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: You may encounter some confusion naming a role super administrator, as super admin is already a term used in WordPress multisites. People will assume you mean a multisite super admin, not a custom role named super admin. The same is true of Network Admin, the admin area for multisite installs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the following permissions from the 'liaison' role:

- create_users
- delete_users
- edit_users
- promote_users
- remove_users

Keep "list_users" so they can see the list, but not edit anything.

The easiest way to remove these permissions is to use a Role Editor plugin. Several are available; you'll select the 'liaison' role, and then through a series of checkboxes, you can remove the above permissions. Once you've saved, you can remove the plugin; WP will keep the permissions as you've saved them.

If you'd rather not use a third-party plugin, you can use code like this instead:

```
// Temporarily remove Liaison
remove_role('liaison');
// Add Liaison role back, with only the permissions you specify here
add_role('liaison', 'Liaison');
$liaison = get_role('liaison');
$liaison->add_cap('read');
$liaison->add_cap('list_users');
```

You may find Liaisons need a couple of other permissions, but this will give them read-only access to content as well as a list of users.

Comment: Oh, crud, I forgot an important piece in the process of oversimplifying.  There actually is a third role, liaison_assistant, which can be created and managed by liaisons.  I forgot to mention them because I forgot it would be important

Comment: I don't think there's a clean way to allow liaisons to create/edit/delete some roles, but not others. You'd probably have to rely on JS, which can be easily circumvented. So you may need to have the higher-level users manage the liaison_assistants instead.

Comment: Hmm, that's not really an option with the client's requirements.  Is there a way to just not show any super admins or other liaisons when a liaison is viewing the user list?